# Rest AUTO_INCREMENT every month

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a database with num_bill as primary key.
And it's an AUTO_INCREMENT.

The column is like this :

> 201512001
>
> 201512002
>
> 201512003
>
> ...
>
> 201512200

And I want to know how should I do when the new month start, to reset AUTO_INCREMENT like this : YYYYMMID

Thanks

Comment: For what puprose are you trying to achieve this. Rather use a created and updated date in your table.

Comment: Bad database design - Now is the time to refactor the design.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do what you want...

```
$year = date("Y");
$month = date("m");
$sql = "ALTER TABLE my_table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=".$year.$month."001;";
```

**EDIT:** Create a cron job that will run at midnight on the first of the month running the code I provided above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kuya, but I have to find a way to do it automatically for every month.

Comment: Thank you a lot Kuya, I just found this solution yesterday, :D